# PhoneGap Android first app changes

Tags: android, cordova, application-error

From the last week on wards i am starting to learn phone gap. I installed and created android app. Basically i am a android developer. I am very new to phonegap. When i import project into eclipse that is imported fine and running also fine.

Here i have some small doubts. I open the www>>index.html file and changed the name `<h1>Apache Cordova</h1>` apache cordova but that name not changed when i am running.

Even if i write the another splash.html file and added to www folder of my project.

splash.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

changed my activity to like this :

```
package io.cordova.hellocordova;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class HelloCordova extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        super.loadUrl("file://android_asset/www/splash.html");
    }
}
```

When i run my app i got

```
Application Error

net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file://android_asset/www/splash.html)
```

Can you please give some direction homw can i change my own screen and how to implement splash screen. please help me.

Thank You

Shankar

Comment: change splash.html to index.html and try

Comment: Hey.. index.html is working fine. But i want to add my own layout file

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using cordova 3.X..

I guess you are making changes in root www foleder i.e. yourProject/www/index.html or yourProject/www/splash.html.

files from root www folder gets copied to www folder of specific platform like for android yourProject\platforms\android\assets\www when you run cordova build command. So changes made in files of root www will reflect in apk only after build command.

Other way is make changes directly in platform's www folder files i.e yourProject\platforms\android\assets\www

hope It will help you. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am using cordova. Means, I need to upload that project to build.phonegap.com and get apk right.

Comment: If i want device level testing what is the way to do that.?

Comment: No, you can directly run cordova build command in command line.. It will do the copy part and generate apk as well. otherwise after build command you can generate apk same as you are doing right now.